# Generic dictionary with value type keys and reference type values

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, .net-framework-version

What code do you write to constrain a generic dictionary named `MyDictionary` to have value-type keys with reference type values?

I think this was my answer:

```
public class MyDictionary<Tkey,TValue>:Dictionary<Tkey,TValue>
where Tkey:struct
where TValue:class
{

}
```

But I'm not sure if this is the right answer..

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would it matter if the generic type is a value type or a reference one for such a dictionary?

Comment: A good question , even i m wondering where such a condition would be helpful. This was posed to me sometime back in a tech interview...

Answer (score 4):

Looks fine to me. One small caveat, you won't be able to use `Nullable` types (e.g. `int?`) as either keys or values in such a dictionary.

From [Constraints on Type Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx):

> `where T: struct` The type argument must be a value type. Any value
>   type except `Nullable` can be specified.
>
> `where T: class` The type argument must be a reference type; this
>   applies also to any class, interface, delegate, or array type.

Answer (score 0):

No Problem. if will perfectly fine.

```
var c = new Dictionary<MyStruct?, MyClass>();
MyStruct? key = new MyStruct(){ X =5};
var value = new MyClass();
c.Add(key, value);
Console.WriteLine(c[key].Prop);
```